# Failing enumerating shellwindows instances

Tags: internet-explorer, winapi, automation

I'am encountering an exception when trying to access shellwindows instances to find IE, so i can attach to it and do web-serfing in auto-mode. I can't find out why is that happening so i just show code snippet. Here it is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

#include <Exdisp.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD dwError;
    IShellWindows *psw;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellWindows, (void **)&psw);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        printf("Error: %d\n", dwError);
        return 0;
    }
    IWebBrowser2* pBrowser2 = 0;
    long nCount = 0;
    hr = psw->get_Count(&nCount);
    printf("%d\n", nCount);
    for (long i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
    {
        _variant_t va(i, VT_I4);
        IDispatch *spDisp;
        hr = psw->Item(va, &spDisp);
        hr = spDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowserApp, (void**)&pBrowser2);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            BSTR name;
            pBrowser2->get_FullName(&name);
            if (wcsstr(name, L"IEXPLORE.EXE"))
            {
                wprintf(L"%ls\n", name);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
    psw->Release();

    VARIANT vEmpty;
    VariantInit(&vEmpty);
    _variant_t URL;
    //URL.SetString("http://googl.ecom");
    pBrowser2->Navigate2(&URL, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);
    Sleep(2000);
    //pBrowser2->GoBack();
    pBrowser2->GoBack();
    Sleep(2000);
    pBrowser2->GoBack();

    //pBrowser2->GoForward();
    //pBrowser2->GoForward();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the line, where execption occurs

```
hr = spDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowserApp, (void**)&pBrowser2);
```

Debugger shows that spDisp is NULL. I've tried to search some information about that issue, but not really found a clue. Where's the problem can be? Thank you for your time!

Comment: `hr = psw->Item(va, &spDisp);` - what's the rationale behind storing the `HRESULT`, and then failing to evaluate error or success? With the inconsistent error checking I would suggest reading [Error Handling in COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679692.aspx).

Comment: It should be `(void**)&pBrowser2` not `(void)&pBrowser2`. Maybe you just want `ShellExecute` to open a website? otherwise browser control is very difficult in plain WinAPI. You can't do it in console window.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, yes that was (void**) from the beginning. That is something wrong with markup. And no, i needed to attach to existing instance and navigate through it. That code not look like very difficult, or what did you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be written this way. (i do not guaranty results)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

#include <Exdisp.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD dwError;
    IShellWindows *psw;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellWindows, (void **)&psw);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        printf("Error: %d\n", dwError);
        return 0;
    }
    IWebBrowser2* pBrowser2 = 0;
    long nCount = 0;
    hr = psw->get_Count(&nCount);
    printf("%d\n", nCount);
    for (long i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
    {
        _variant_t va(i, VT_I4);
        IDispatch *spDisp;
        hr = psw->Item(va, &spDisp);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
            hr = spDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowserApp, (void )&pBrowser2);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                BSTR name;
                pBrowser2->get_FullName(&name);
                if (wcsstr(name, L"IEXPLORE.EXE"))
                {
                    wprintf(L"%ls\n", name);

                    VARIANT vEmpty;
                    VariantInit(&vEmpty);
                    _variant_t URL;
                    //URL.SetString("http://googl.ecom");
                    pBrowser2->Navigate2(&URL, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);
                    Sleep(2000);
                    //pBrowser2->GoBack();
                    pBrowser2->GoBack();
                    Sleep(2000);
                    pBrowser2->GoBack();

                }
                pBrowser2->Release();
            }
        }
    }
    psw->Release();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @IInspectable, error reporting in COM is not just checking GetLastError(); it is little bit more complicated, that 's why it was ommited.

Comment: If you find COM error handling (which is likely the most straight forward error handling there is) complicated, you probably should not attempt to answer a question on this topic. Specifically, I'm referring to `HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);`. Why do you store the return value and then fail to evaluate it?

Comment: the most straight forward?. take a look at this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: i am not trying to write a book, i am just trying to help him to avoid the exception which is the subject here.

Comment: Uhm... that's the **optional** `IErrorInfo` interface, that a COM object can implement. Error handling in COM is as simple as calling [SUCCEEDED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197.aspx) or [FAILED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474.aspx). Maybe you should not write answers on topics you do not understand.

Comment: Thanks! thats working smoothly now, Still wondering why hr = psw->Item(va, &spDisp); could return S_FAIL. If anything will go wrong i will deal with error handling then. Thank both of you, issue is solved!